# Keras equivalent of Caffe's 'cpu_data()' method?

Tags: python, c++, keras, caffe

## Example

I'm trying to understand a specific code written in C++ version of Caffe to port it in Python version of Keras.

Obviously, layer in the Caffe can be defined as the example below:

```
template <typename Dtype>
void ROIPoolingLayer<Dtype>::LayerSetUp(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
```

where bottom is a one-dimensional array that takes inputs and top is a one-dimensional array that produces outputs.

Then soon after, few parameters are already set using `bottom` vector:

```
template <typename Dtype>
void ROIPoolingLayer<Dtype>::LayerSetUp(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
  ROIPoolingParameter roi_pool_param = this->layer_param_.roi_pooling_param();
  CHECK_GT(roi_pool_param.pooled_h(), 0)
      << "pooled_h must be > 0";
  CHECK_GT(roi_pool_param.pooled_w(), 0)
      << "pooled_w must be > 0";
  pooled_height_ = roi_pool_param.pooled_h();
  pooled_width_ = roi_pool_param.pooled_w();
  spatial_scale_ = roi_pool_param.spatial_scale();
  LOG(INFO) << "Spatial scale: " << spatial_scale_;
}

template <typename Dtype>
void ROIPoolingLayer<Dtype>::Reshape(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
  channels_ = bottom[0]->channels();
  height_ = bottom[0]->height();
  width_ = bottom[0]->width();
  top[0]->Reshape(bottom[1]->num(), channels_, pooled_height_,
      pooled_width_);
  max_idx_.Reshape(bottom[1]->num(), channels_, pooled_height_,
      pooled_width_);
}
```

And if we expand code furthermore they use `cpu_data` method:

```
template <typename Dtype>
void ROIPoolingLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
  const Dtype* bottom_data = bottom[0]->cpu_data();
  const Dtype* bottom_rois = bottom[1]->cpu_data();
```

[reference to full code](https://github.com/gogartom/caffe-textmaps/blob/5c11645693320c7ba79bd0ddd646cd786c6bcf6f/src/caffe/layers/roi_pooling_layer.cpp).

---

## Question

From Caffe documentation:

> As we are often interested in the values as well as the gradients of
>   the blob, a Blob stores two chunks of memories, data and diff. The
>   former is the normal data that we pass along, and the latter is the
>   gradient computed by the network.
>
> Further, as the actual values could be stored either on the CPU and on
>   the GPU, there are two different ways to access them: the const way,
>   which does not change the values, and the mutable way, which changes
>   the values:
>
> `const Dtype* cpu_data() const; Dtype* mutable_cpu_data();`

So according to description above, is `bottom_data[0].cpu_data()` defined in the recent code block above simply an array stored in CPU registers containing input data and partial derivative with respect to error? If so, how could I replicate such code in Keras? Is it even significant in Keras (where the layer is either already evaluated or just an empty shape)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bottom_data[0].cpu_data()` is the **method** that will return you a constant pointer to the memory of the first input blob. If necessary, the data will be first copied from GPU memory.

You do not need to operate on such a low-level concepts in Keras.

Look at this code from the [Keras example](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/):

```
def call(self, x):
    return K.dot(x, self.kernel)
```

Here you return the result of the dot product between the input tensor and the layer's kernel.

Unlike Caffe, in Keras you (mostly) define operations on *tensors*, not on memory arrays. Tensors will be filled with the actual data on execution time, when running a session. Keras backend will take care of all the memory operations needed to perform the `K.dot` operation (which also returns a tensor).

Also, you can choose which device will be used to place your tensor: [FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#device-parallelism). Again, Keras will perform all necessary operations under the hood.

Comment: Well that's quite interesting. Also I've found out that it is optimal to directly communicate with a backend when compile time is concern, e.g Tensorflow backend has `tf.image.resize_images` which is quite helpful. I just wanted to know what was a difference between `bottom_data[0]` and `bottom_data[0].cpu_data()`, where I guess `bottom_data[0]` is just an object containing methods which will return the actual data. Also your last statement about device placement is very useful. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: bottom_data[0] will return you a Blob: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html. Blob is wrapper around the memory chunk which provides many auxiliary functions.

Comment: Yes I have viewed that source before, but documentation is still brief I believe. Helpful source was [blob.hpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/blob.hpp) which explains methods of Blob class very well in the comments. But for now Keras and Tensorflow backend is sufficient I believe.